# How to ignore part of url in urlManager rules?

Tags: routes, yii2

I want this url `/admin/personal/index` to run `personal` controller and `index` action, so i add this rule to urlManager

```
'admin/<controller>/<action>' => '<controller>/<action>'
```

but it seems, that he think `admin` - is controller and `personal` - is action. But i want to ignore `admin` part of url at all. How can i achieve it? (without .htaccess, if possible)

also try Jorgen's solution, but still get a 404 error. And in logs this line:

```
Request parsed with URL rule: <module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>
```

## main-local config

```
'urlManager' => [
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => [
            'admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ],
    ],
```

## .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

It works only if i wrote next rule

```
'<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

but in this case 'admin' prefix, of course, not adding to url. But directly, it works fine.

I found the reason: there were another rules in common configs.

Thx, **Jorgen**, for helping! **Question closed**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
'admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
```

You need to specify the Regular Expression for the parameters.
You might also have a conflict if you have a parameter for `<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>` before this setting. Try putting it as the first parameter.

From the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#named-parameters)

> A URL rule can be associated with a few named query parameters which are specified in the pattern in the format of , where ParamName specifies the parameter name and RegExp is an optional regular expression used to match parameter values. If RegExp is not specified, it means the parameter value should be a string without any slash.
>
> Note: You can only specify regular expressions for parameters. The rest part of a pattern is considered as plain text.

Comment: still get 404 error. But in log i have this: "Request parsed with URL rule: <module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>". I'm sure that the rule applied correctly, but Yii still parse it in default way.

Comment: I checked that without rules, Yii logged: "No matching URL rules. Using default URL parsing logic.", so above route message is not the default.

Comment: Did you try with `admin` or just with `<module\w+>`? i'm not sure yii recognizes module. And did you place your rule on top of the rules array?

Comment: I've got only one rule exactly as in the question

Comment: May be Yii think about 'admin' like this is a module?

Comment: I just tried my solution in a clean yii2 install. It works. i obviously misunderstood your question. You want to add 'admin' to all your urls, right?

Comment: Yeap, i want just add 'admin'. I'll ad some config notes to this question. Just a minute

Comment: Can you show, what do you have in your Yii log's message in category "yii\web\UrlRule::parseRequest" (#6, most likely)?

Comment: Sure. "Request parsed with URL rule: admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>"

Comment: But i'm getting this "Request parsed with URL rule: <module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>", do you have any ideas? May be i need to overwrite this behavior, but i dont know how.

Comment: What action / controller are you trying with?

Comment: I got it, there were another rules in common configs, they're overwrite my. My mistake, sorry!

Comment: Question can be closed, thank you very much for help!

Comment: Sorry, but i have not enough reputation to vote for your answer =(

Comment: No worries. You accepted the answer. Im Just happy to help.